# SSIS logging provider has failed to open the log access is denied

Tags: ssis

I have a an SSIS master package which runs some child packages within it.
Logging is enabled for all packages.

Within the master package, we initially call lets say child package 1, the log file will be created for that package and then tries to re-run the same child package.

If I run the package as an admin, two log files are created for the child package which is exactly what we expect to happen but running it as another account which does have permission to execute package and write log files fails when running the child package for the second time within the master package.

"SSIS logging provider has failed to open the log access is denied"

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Master package runs the child twice?

Comment: Yes, the child package does different things in different stages but that is something else.I wonder why log file cannot be created by the same user for the second time!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message with a SSIS package not being able to open basic file system functions on a package that was previously operating fine on another system.

The files the package was trying to access were set to read-only. Once I removed that restriction the package operated normally.